# string.replace not working for me

Tags: c#, asp.net, string

I have this code:

```
string encodedKeywordsQueryValue = HttpUtility.UrlEncode(HttpContext.Current.Request.QueryString["keywords"]);
query = query.Replace(HttpContext.Current.Request.QueryString["keywords"], encodedKeywordsQueryValue);
```

where

```
HttpContext.Current.Request.QueryString["keywords"] = "abc& abc"
```

and

```
encodedKeywordsQueryValue=abc%26+abc
```

My old string value is not getting replaced with new one.

Can anyone suggest me to do this? I have tried combination of remove and insert methods of string but not getting desired results.

Kindly help me with this.

Comment: What is value of query variable?

Comment: This method exist since .NET 2.0. And it is used by tons of developers for years. I don't think you get an unexpected behaviour such a basic operation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> HttpContext.Current.Request.QueryString["keywords"]="abc& abc" and 
>   encodedKeywordsQueryValue=abc%26+abc

reading the documentation of replace method would tell you that it does not know about URL encoding and does not care - it is a string method. So, work on unencoded strings. There is no like style behavior - it is an exact "match and replace".

I would suggest you make a unit test for this behavior and then work out how you would like it to be - then you could for example also make a post here that is somehow baseline useful because it would have an exact example of which behavior does not work, not some riddle for us to solve.

Answer (score 0):

you should have an exact string on the left side of replace. it doesn't act like 'LIKE'. see the example below:

```
string str1 = "abc";
string str2 = "abc&def";
str2.replace("d", str1);
```

result will be:

```
abc&abcef
```

hope it helps